# Using data step to append custom text to ODS stream

Tags: email, sas, sas-ods

I'm trying to print out a table to an email destination and then put some custom comments at the end.  When I try and run the below code I get the message:

```
ERROR: File is in use, .
```

My code is:

```
filename mymail email content_type="text/html"
                      to=("myemail@myemail.com")
                      from=("myemail@myemail.com")
                      subject="My Report";

ods html3 body=mymail style=sasweb;

proc print data=sashelp.class noobs;  
run;

data _null_; 
  file mymail ;
  put "I want this to appear at the bottom of the email.";
run;

ods html3 close;

filename mymail clear;
```

I've tried googling for help but the search terms are so vague it's tough to narrow it down to this specific problem.  Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify - I want all the results in the body of the email.  I don't want the results sent as an attachment.  Also, if you comment out just the data step in the above code, the email works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to test these two approaches in an actual email, but they did avoid the (replicable) `Error: File is in use` message..

```
filename mymail "C:/temp/test.html";
ods html3 body=mymail style=sasweb;

proc print data=sashelp.class noobs;  
footnote "Approach 1: I want this to appear at the bottom of the email.";
run;

data _null_; 
  file print ;
  put "Approach 2: I also want this to appear at the bottom of the email.";
run;

ods html3 close;
filename mymail clear;
```

The change is to use the `file print` reference in the data step.  According to the [SAS Documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000171874.htm):

*PRINT is a reserved fileref that directs the output that is produced by any PUT statements to the same file as the output that is produced by SAS procedures.*

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear to me whether you actually needed the data step to do any data processing, versus just printing text.  I recently had a similar challenge, but my focus was on simply printing text, so you can use the ODS text function:

ODS HTML3 text="Approach 3: Use the ODS TEXT function to put text anywhere.";

Depending upon your html destination, you can use css or html tags to govern font, size, alignment, etc.  I'll guess you're using html3 for outlook compatibility, so css tags won't work.